# codeigniter jquery's autocomplete not working but no error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I'm new to javascript and I tried to follow [this](http://www.codersmount.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-with-database/) tutorial.

I have a textbox(input) and I want to use the jQuery's autocomplete by loading some data from MySQL.

This is my controller code :

```
public function autocomplete() {
    if($this->input->post('txt_nama'))
        $this->absensi_m->get_umat($this->input->post('txt_nama'));

    /*if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->absensi_m->get_umat($q);
    }*/
}
```

This is my model :

```
public function get_umat($word) {
    $this->db->select('nama', 'tanggal_lahir');
    $this->db->like('nama', $word);
    $query = $this->db->get('msumat');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $new_row['label'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['nama']));
            $new_row['value'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['tanggal_lahir']));
            //build array
            $row_set[] = $new_row;
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set);
    }
}
```

And this is my javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#txt_nama").autocomplete({
                source: "autocomplete"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I tried to inspect the javascript by using firefox's firebug and GC's developer tool, and this is what i got :

```
<input type="text" id="txt_nama" name="txt_nama" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Notice that the **autocomplete** is **off**. I guess this is the problem so i tried to turn it on by adding this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#txt_nama").attr("autocomplete", "on");
        });
```

The **autocomplete** element is turned **on** when i add this code, but the autocomplete is still **not** working.

I also tried to use echo, but **none** of my echo is working :

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        echo num_rows();
        echo 'a';

        foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $new_row['label'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['nama']));
            $new_row['value'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['tanggal_lahir']));
            //build array
            $row_set[] = $new_row;
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set);
        //return row_set;
    }
```

What am I missing?

**NOTE :**
I just wondering about `Routes`, is it related to this error?because normally, people use `controller/method` in `source:` (JavaScript), but I can't do that because the generated route will have double controller (`index.php/absensi/absensi/autocomplete`), so I remove the `controller` and just use the method (`source: "absensi"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer :

1. DONT use echo, it will break the jquery.
2. Use `if (isset($_GET['term']))` instead of `$this->input->post()`
3. Use `source: "<?php echo site_url('absensi/autocomplete'); ?>"` in the jquery

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're using the `source` option incorrectly. From the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data.

If you meant to have `source` pointing to your `autocomplete` function, you need to give your controller name like they have on the demo you linked:

```
source: "birds/get_birds" // path to the get_birds method
```

Comment: Also using site_url method from CI might help.

Comment: @MihaiIonescu Thanks for your help. I tried to use source: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/absensi/autocomplete", it generate the same route like i just use "autocomplete" and its still not working :D

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I also used to believe that, but when i use something like "absensi/autocomplete" (absensi is my controller and autocomplete is a method in it) it will give me error 404 (because the generated route is "index.php/absensi/absensi/autocomplete" - note that the absensi is called twice, which is cause the 404 error), but if i just use "autocomplete" theres no error in my firebug/Dev console :D

Comment: Please see my edited question, really need help here. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

**Model**

```
public function get_umat($word) {
    $this->db->select('nama', 'tanggal_lahir');
    $this->db->like('nama', $word);
    $query = $this->db->get('msumat');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $new_row['label'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['nama']));
            $new_row['value'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['tanggal_lahir']));
            //build array
            $row_set[] = $new_row;
        }
        return $row_set;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function autocomplete() {
    if($this->input->post('txt_nama'))
        echo json_encode($this->absensi_m->get_umat($this->input->post('txt_nama')));

}
```

You should place `echo json_encode()` in `autocomplete()` but not in model..

Comment: Thanks for your help :D it seems your controller code give an error, im trying to solve it now :D